# renderscript assertion failure !rsAssert failed: !"ScriptGroup:setInput kid not found"

Tags: android, renderscript

I dont understand why this assertion is thown. I believe I have the correct code sequence for setting up the scriptgroup

```
ScriptGroup.Builder sBuilder = new ScriptGroup.Builder(mRS);
sBuilder.addKernel(K1.getKernelID_root());
sBuilder.addKernel(K2.getKernelID_root());
sBuilder.addConnection(inAlloc.getType(),
                        K1.getKernelID_root(),
                        K2.getKernelID_root());
ScriptGroup sGroup = sBuilder.create();
sGroup.setInput(K1.getKernelID_root(), inAlloc);
sGroup.setOutput(k2.getKernelID_root(), outAlloc);
sGroup.execute();
```

I ask because I find that K1 executes, however, K2 does not execute at all. Instead, this assertion is thrown. Could this assertion have anything to do with this behavior?

@jason
I have solved this issue by qualifying the kernels with **attribute**((kernel)) and then the scriptgroup execution triggers correctly. This avoided the assertion and I can clearly see that both kernels are executing as expected. However, just a few more details on the scenario when this assertion occurred. My previous definition of kernels was `void root(short3 *out, uint32_t out_x, uint32_t out_y)`. So when kernels were defined as such(i.e defined as root) , it appears the assertion is thrown. It looks like there is some sort of clash between ScriptGroup.SetInput and if kernels are defined as root. When I get a chance, I will try to reproduce this issue. For now, I have gone past this issue as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problem in the source.  Any chance you could post some more context on what K1 & K2 are ?

The assert you are seeing does indicate a problem.